# Declarative Rollup Summaries Deployment

Tags: salesforce, rollup, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, declarative-programming

**My requirement is that I have DLRS and lookup roll-up summaries in one of my production orgs. Now, I want to export those lookup roll-up summaries and then import them into another org. Alternatively, I am seeking any other method to achieve this.**